# how to generic ng-multiselect-dropdown for Angular reactive form properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In Angular, how should I write ng-multiselect-dropdown to make ng-multiselect-dropdown generic when used in the Angular reactive form properties?

I am a beginner .I worked hard for this .But I could not . Please explain detail for generic ng-multiselect-dropdown .